# When building bootstrap, how can I select a different build path other than 'dist'?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

While building [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) from source code, the default build path is `dist`, can I specify another path without changing the `Gruntfile.js` too much?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to build it?

Comment: I have modified the LESS file and hope to apply it to my website. For now, I have to compile it and copy the output `css` file to my `css` folder. @staticx

Answer (score 1):

Just change instances where you see `dest: dist/***` into your desired location. Quickly looking at the gruntfile, it looks like you can basically do a replaceall on dist to whatever you want -- it will rename the task names but if you run the default task it should turn out fine.

If this doesn't work, just change `dest` and `cwd`, etc. fields to your desired location.